# How to fetch data from firestore using .where(GreaterThan, and LessThan) condition. - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch data from firestore using the `.where()` condition.

```
 Query adsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('All ads')        
    .where('adPrice',
        isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: '2000') 
    .where('adPrice',
        isLessThanOrEqualTo: '115000') 
    .limit(adsPerPage);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await adsRef.get();
```

When using only one condition (eg:  `.where('adPrice',isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: '2000')` ) works but dosen't fetch all documents[Just fetching random documents].

And when using both condtions it retruns null even though the DB has matching data.

**Is there any other way to fetch data from firestore within two numbers? (in between 2000 to 115000)**

Comment: You should add some error handling to your query and see what the message says.

Comment: Why are you comparing to string?

Comment: @EmilGi yeah it was the problem. When it's String it just fetches random documents, and once I've changed it to int it works as expected. :)

Answer (score 2):

Two inequality conditions are not valid in one firestore query. wrap you block of code in try catch and you will see the error.

Alternatively you can query both of your conditions separately and then merge the results like this:

```
void getAds() async {
    List<Future<QuerySnapshot>> futures = [];
    var firstQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('All ads')
        .where('adPrice', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: '2000')
        .getDocuments();
var secondQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('All ads')
        .where('adPrice', isLessThanOrEqualTo: '115000')
        .getDocuments();

    futures.add(firstQuery);
    futures.add(secondQuery);

    List<QuerySnapshot> results = await Future.wait(futures);
    results.forEach((res) {
      res.documents.forEach((docResults) {
        print(docResults.data);
      });
    });
  }
```

Please do try this and let me know if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: What you're saying isn't exactly true - you can have multiple range filters on the *same field*.  You just can't have multiple range filters on *different fields* in the same query.  Be sure to read the documentation to understand what the limitations are.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries